# peewee self-referential many-to-many design and query questions

Tags: python, peewee

I'm new to Python and peewee and this is my first post here.

In addition, I'm nearly blind so please excuse any typos :)

After stydying the peewee docs and searching through the many posts here and elsewhere,
I still have questions about how self-referential, many-to-many designs work in peewee.

My goal is to query a sports database. The code at the end does most the job but there are two issues that remain unresolved (**see below**).

**Edit: I solved question #1 below regarding filtering for a specific tournament (and I will post the updated program shortly).**.

**Edit #2: I'll take that back! Upon further testing I realized my solution for #1 does not work :(**

**Edit #3: I finally answered my own question :)

So... I fixed a couple of typos in the statement of

the issue below (in the table values)

and I'll post the solution in my answer.**

## Statement of the problem

Here are the test data tables (the tables will contain more fields eventually)

```
        Tournaments
+------------+------------+
| tournament | tournament |
|    id      |    name    |  
+------------+------------+
|    101     | US Open    |
|    102     | US Closed  |
+------------+------------+

      Players
+--------+--------+
| player | player |
|   id   |  name  |
+--------+--------+
|    1   | John   |
|    2   | Tony   |
|    3   | Ken    |
|    4   | George |
+--------+--------+

               Matches
+------------+--------+-------+-------+
| tournament | winner | loser |       |
|     id     |   id   |  id   | event |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+
|    101     |   1    |   4   | Semis |
|    101     |   2    |   3   | Semis |
|    101     |   1    |   2   | Final |
|    102     |   1    |   2   | Semis |
|    102     |   3    |   4   | Semis |
|    102     |   1    |   3   | Final |
+------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

The desired result is to show wins for player 1 in
the US Closed tournament (pid=1, tid=102):

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| Loser id | Loser name |  Event   |
+----------+------------+----------+
|    2     |   Tony     |  Semis   |
|    3     |   Ken      |  Final   |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I mentioned two items above: 1: "Filter by tournament id to eliminate the first two rows of the result." and 2: "Pull the event description, "Semis", from the match table."

Comment: What confuses me it that when I run the SQL generated by my peewee code I get what I expect but when I print the result of the query using pprint(model_to_dict(match)) I get different results. Compare the output of my ptogram and the output of sqlite above.

Answer (score 1):

My answer covers the original requirements and, goes a bit further by adding the tournament info in the resulting table.

Below is the program output followed by the complete program.

## Program output

```
                 John's wins in the US Open
event      w_pid  tname      pid    id    l_pid  pname      tid
-------  -------  -------  -----  ----  -------  -------  -----
Semis          1  US Open      4     1        4  George     101
Final          1  US Open      2     3        2  Tony       101
                 John's wins in the US Closed
event      w_pid  tname        pid    id    l_pid  pname      tid
-------  -------  ---------  -----  ----  -------  -------  -----
Semis          1  US Closed      2     4        2  Tony       102
Final          1  US Closed      3     6        3  Ken        102
```

## The solution

```
from peewee import *
from pprint import pprint
import tabulate

db = SqliteDatabase('app.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Tournament(BaseModel):
    tid       = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    tname     = CharField()

class Player(BaseModel):
    pid   = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    pname = CharField()

class Match(BaseModel):
    w_pid = ForeignKeyField(Player) # Winner pid
    l_pid = ForeignKeyField(Player) # Loser pid
    tid   = ForeignKeyField(Tournament)
    event = CharField()

db.drop_tables([Player, Match, Tournament])
db.create_tables([Player, Match, Tournament])

# ----- Tournaments
Tournament.create(tid=101, tname="US Open")
Tournament.create(tid=102, tname="US Closed")

# ----- Players
Player.create(pid=1, pname="John")
Player.create(pid=2, pname="Tony")
Player.create(pid=3, pname="Ken")
Player.create(pid=4, pname="George")

# ----- US Open Matches
Match.create(tid=101, w_pid=1, l_pid=4, event="Semis")
Match.create(tid=101, w_pid=2, l_pid=3, event="Semis")
Match.create(tid=101, w_pid=1, l_pid=2, event="Final")

# ----- US Closed Matches
Match.create(tid=102, w_pid=1, l_pid=2, event="Semis")
Match.create(tid=102, w_pid=3, l_pid=4, event="Semis")
Match.create(tid=102, w_pid=1, l_pid=3, event="Final")

def show_wins(tid, pid):
    Winner = Player.alias()
    wins = (Player
        .select(Player, Match, Tournament)
        .join(Match, on=(Player.pid == Match.l_pid))
        .join(Tournament, on=(Tournament.tid == Match.tid))
        .where(Tournament.tid == tid)
        .switch(Winner)
        .join(Winner, on=(Winner.pid == Match.w_pid))
        .where(Winner.pid == pid)
        .dicts()
    )
    header = wins[0].keys()
    rows =  [x.values() for x in wins]
    print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, header))

print("                 John's wins in the US Open")
show_wins(101, 1)

print("                 John's wins in the US Closed")
show_wins(102, 1)

db.close()
```